# find and replace on a HTMLelement.INNERHTML?

Tags: javascript, html

```
 var e = document.getElementById('anelement');
 e.innerHTML = f.anelement
```

inside `anelement` I'd like to replace every occurance of a certain word e.g `apple` with `orange` how would I go about doing this?

Comment: Depending on what your replacing you might damage the HTML structure. I.e. change tags. If possible avoid string replacing on `.innerHTML`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`innerHTML` is a `String` object which has the [`replace`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp) method:

```
e.innerHTML = f.anelement.innerHTML.replace("apple", "orange");
```

---

**Edit**

As [Matt Brock](https://stackoverflow.com/users/313969/matt-brock) pointed out in comments, a simple `replace` does not differentiate between whole words and substrings. A more precise solution, using regular expressions, would be:

```
var result = "apple to orange".replace(/\b(apple)\b/g, "orange");
// evaluates to "orange to orange"
```

Comment: Probably want to add more logic than that.  That would replace all occurrences of "Snapple" with "Snorange".

Comment: Doesn't work for the string "apple apple to orange" the regex needs to be global. `/\b(apple)\b/g`